# python3.6 matplotlib extremely slow

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I don't know why it is extremely slow when I plot with matplotlib. I tried a simple plot and it takes more than a minute to complete.

I tried install different version of matplotlib from 2.1.0 to the current version and all same result.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mlp
import datetime

print(mlp.__version__)
print(datetime.datetime.now())
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 9, 16])
print(datetime.datetime.now())
plt.savefig('testplot.png')
print(datetime.datetime.now())
```

output:

```
    myserver:~$./test.py
    3.0.2 
    2019-01-24 13:50:56.040192 
    2019-01-24 13:52:09.886336 
    2019-01-24 13:52:09.976869
```

Comment: Since you are running this on a server, is there a difference if you use `import matplotlib as mlp; mpl.use("Agg"); import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; ...` (mind the order and the backend set).

Comment: Matplotlib tries to build a font-cache in `~/.matplotlib`;  is it possible that it is doing this anew each time you start matplotlib?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I added your code and it flies now. Thanks